# My possibly fraudulent proof of $f_n$ Cauchy in measure => $f_n -> liminf$ in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

This result seems too convenient and I feel like Folland would have used this to prove proposition 2.30 if this was true.

My "proof":

Let $f_n$ be Cauchy in measure.

By definition of $\liminf f_n(x)$, 
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in X$ there exists an $m_{x,n}> n$ such that 
$|\liminf f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon / 2$

Now consider the set {$x\in X : |f_n(x) -\liminf f_n(x)| > \epsilon$}

By triangle inequality, $\epsilon \leq |f_n(x) -\liminf f_n(x)| \leq |f_n(x) - f_{m_{x,n}}(x)| + |f_{m_{x,n}}(x) - \liminf f_n(x)|$

but since $|\liminf f_n(x) - f_{m_{x,n}}(x)| \leq \epsilon / 2$, we must have that $ \epsilon/2 \leq |f_n(x) -\liminf f_n(x)| $

therefore, the set

{$x\in X : |f_n(x) -\liminf f_n(x)| > \epsilon$} $\subset$ {$x\in X : |f_n(x) - f_{m_{x,n}}(x)| > \epsilon/2$}

but the measure of the set on the right approaches to zero as $n$ tends to infinity (since $m_{x,n}> n$)

therefore the measure of the set {$x\in X : |f_n(x) -\liminf f_n(x)| > \epsilon$} tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity

Is there anything wrong with this proof?

thank you

Comment: It's liminf of *what*?

Comment: sorry, lim inf fn(x). fixed.

Comment: Use  `\liminf` (with a backslash) for the limit inferior.

Comment: Yes, the proof is wrong. You only know that measure of $\{x:|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| >\epsilon\} \to 0$ as $n, m \to \infty$ and you cannot replace $m$ by an integer that depends on $x$.

Comment: If $\liminf f_n(x)=\infty$ or $-\infty$ then you cannot achieve $\epsilon$-closeness to $f_m(x)$ like you want to.  Now, it actually happens to be true that $\liminf f_n(x)\in(-\infty,\infty)$ almost everywhere.  But you would need to show that to be true.  There may be other problems with your proof that I have not noticed yet.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think that is permitted since $m_{x,n}>n$.  So, if $n\to\infty$ then $m_{x,n}\to\infty$ also.